# How to make child re-render upon refresh using RefreshControl in RN?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

below are how my components are aligned in my RN app

```
  <View>
    <ScrollView>
      <BannerContainer />
      <CampaignContainer />
      <BrandContainer />
      <Infographic />
      <Seo />
    </ScrollView>
    <BackToTop onTap={this.onBackToTopTap} />
  </View>
```

In componentDidMount of every child element under ScrollView, I dispatch asynchronous actions. For example

```
const { dispatch } = this.props
    dispatch(fetchBanners())
```

Now what I am trying to do is to add RefreshControl, in my App.js like this

```
<View>
    <ScrollView ref="scrollView" refreshControl={
      <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
        onRefresh={this._onRefresh.bind(this)}
      />
    }>
      <BannerContainer />
      <CampaignContainer />
      <BrandContainer />
      <Infographic />
      <Seo />
    </ScrollView>
    <BackToTop onTap={this.onBackToTopTap} />
  </View>
```

I want to know how can I make my page reload, i.e. call componentDidMount of each child inside _onRefresh function so that all the data is loaded again?

Comment: I believe it's just as simple as calling your fetches inside the `_onRefresh`

Answer (score 0):

You may try this..

```
_onRefresh() {
  this.setState({ refreshing: true });
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ refreshing: false });
  }, 1000);
}
```

..and in your ScrollView put you components inside this condition. This will cause a re-render as the refreshing state changes when you pull to refresh.

```
{!this.state.refreshing && [
  <BannerContainer />,
  <CampaignContainer />,
  <BrandContainer />,
  <Infographic />,
  <Seo />
]}
```

Note: Don't forget to give a key to each component in the array